# cronjob every sunday of the week

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

Hi all I have an ubuntu server where I want to create a cron every sunday al 23:00
I have read manual and I have try to use some cron generator.
I have tried in this mode:

```
0 23 * * * root test.php
```

But this I think that every day works right?
How can I make that this script only works on Sunday?

Thanks

Comment: If you had bothered to read the documentation this would have been trivial to figure out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0 23 * * 0 root test.php
```

last field is"day of week" and 0 represents sunday.